# .net API requests in specific time range

Tags: c#, .net

I have a controller which handle post request and store data in database.

Now I need to create some logic which will be able to find the maximum value from multiple requests in one minute.

I tried to implement timer as Singleton service and start the timer with first request. After timer elapsed I stop it and now I want to store the data in database.

The problem with this is I'm getting error >cannot use scoped service inside a singleton

My question is, is this good approach? Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: i'd do the analysis after the fact, not storing things in memory.

Comment: Agreed, store the data as it happens then run your analysis of the data offline. Also, now, because you have the raw data, you can perform any analysis on the data you want without having to push new code in to production.